# WCF : The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, web-config, c#-3.0

My Client web.config has :

```
 <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="dataConfiguration">
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>   

        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>                  

                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISchedulingService" closeTimeout="01:10:00"
                  openTimeout="00:11:00" receiveTimeout="01:10:00" sendTimeout="01:10:00"
                  allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
                  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                          realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>

            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

        <client>

            <endpoint address="http://localhost:1234/SchedulingService.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISchedulingService"
                behaviorConfiguration="dataConfiguration"             contract="SchedulingService.ISchedulingService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISchedulingService" />
        </client>
```

And HostApp web.config has :

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>      
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="dataConfiguration">
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>       
          <!-- To avoid disclosing m7tadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And ServiceApp web.config has :

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="14400"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- increase the size of data that can be serialized -->
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now,
In my Controller method in client, I tried to pass to the service
 * List of 3600 string[] to service
and
 * Instead, A string of 3600 row details separated by a delimiter (Excel parsed sheet)

(PS : There are 12 string values for each row  (and total rows = 3600))

But I keep getting :

```
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.
```

Even for 200 row upload.
Please guide. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It still threw the same error for even 200 records list... So finally I decided to call the same in chunks rather at once..
 thanks for guiding

```
   int chunkSize = 100;

   for (var i = 0; i < Details.Count; i += chunkSize)
                {
                    List<List<string>> DetailsChunk = schoolDetails.Skip(i).Take(chunkSize).ToList();
                    result = scheduleClient.AddDetails(DetailsChunk, savedFileName);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any bindings or endpoints explicitly defined in the service's config file, so you are getting a default endpoint with `basicHttpBinding`, with default values for the binding.  Try either a) defining a `basicHttpBinding` in the service config and assigning it to an explicitly defined endpoint or b) define a default `basicHttpBinding` that will be used for all services that use that config file.

**Option a**

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>                  
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISchedulingService" closeTimeout="01:10:00"
             openTimeout="00:11:00" receiveTimeout="01:10:00" 
             sendTimeout="01:10:00" allowCookies="false" 
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"   
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                   realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="SchedulingService">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISchedulingService"
              contract="SchedulingService.ISchedulingService" 
              name="BasicHttpBinding_ISchedulingService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

In the above configuration, a `basicHttpBinding` is defined with the name "BasicHttpBinding_ISchedulingService", and this definition is assigned to the service endpoint via the `bindingConfiguration` attribute of the `<endpoint>` element.

**Option b**

Similar to option a above, except the binding congifuration section omits the `name` attribute, and no service endpoint is defined.  The defined binding configuration will be used for all services that use `basicHttpBinding` unless overridden for an explicitly defined endpoint via the `bindingConfiguration` attribute.

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>                  
    <binding closeTimeout="01:10:00" openTimeout="00:11:00"
      <!-- Remaining binding conifguration snipped for brevity -->
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```